# utm_odometry_node frame convention

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, frame, gps-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using the utm_odometry_node to input the position of my robot to another node.
If I'm right the convention used in the /odom topic is:

- X axis points backwards
- Y axis points right
- Z axis points up

But I need this to be in standard convention, this is: X forward, Y left, Z up.

Any suggestion on how this can be done is appreciated.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86661/utm_odometry_node-frame-convention/) by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually GPS receivers do not provide orientation, thus there is no information about where is front of your robot. The coordinate frames you described are both correct [right handed frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#In_three_dimensions). The first one is just rotated around Z-coordinate by `pi`.

If GPS coordinates are augmented with orientation from some other source, then you may need to check the transformation between `child_frame_id` (usually `base_footprint`) of `utm_odometry_node` and base frame of your robot (usually `base_link`).

Also, note that all coordinate frames in ROS are relative and depend on coordinate frame that you consider as fixed frame.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1